# Get xml variable value from a different file

Tags: xml

I am working with a software api that uses xml.
This xml file stores an svg image as its raw bytes inside the xml (like the following)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
    <"They shall not be named...">
        <Map map="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PD94bWwgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4wIiBlbmNvZGluZz0iVVRGLTgiIHN0YW5kYWxvbmU9Im5vIj8+&#10;
CjxzdmcKICAgeG1sbnM6ZGM9Imh0dHA6Ly9wdXJsLm9yZy9kYy9lbGVtZW50cy8xLjEvIgog&#10;
ICB4bWxuczpjYz0iaHR0cDovL2NyZWF0aXZlY29tbW9ucy5vcmcvbnMjIgogICB4bWxuczpy&#10;
...
```

I need to miniplate this xml file and the svg image that is being used causes the xml file to be of excess of 10 MB. This makes interacting with the xml file difficult.

What I would like to do is store the raw data inside of a different file "mySvgImage.txt" and have xml read that file to extract the needed information. Something like

```
<?xml version"1.0"?>
    <"They shall not be named...">
        <Map map=FromFile("mySvgImage.txt")/>
```

I hope something like this is possible and I am open to any and all ideas.
Or if there is a way to read in another xml file inside of a existing xml file (kind of like a import call).

```
<?xml version"1.0"?>
    <"They shall not be named...">
        import longSvgFile.xml
        <myChanges>
        ...
        </myChanges>
```

Thank you for taking your time to read this.

Comment: XML is not a programming language.  What language and libraries are you using?

Comment: Hello,
The software in question is a tracking software. To use the software, it needs to have an xml file. This file contains the image and specific zones inside the image (the image is a floorplan). I am trying to make these zones. Once I am able to start tracking tags, then I will be using java to interact with data, but java has no role in the creation of the xml file nor does it ever read it.
Thank you.

Comment: @MattSchramm have looked at XML transformation? It may  not need what you want (and I doubt plain xml can anyway) but if you use transform, you would be able to produce one.

Comment: @vish, I don't believe that will work but I will investigate further. For now I am using a python script to combine my image.xml file and my zones.xml files together.

Comment: @MattSchramm yes, that would work nicely (python). If you cannot use python (or any other scripting for that matter), couple of times I had used simple copy command: https://superuser.com/questions/958296/concatenate-multiple-files-with-windows-command-line